# Upload folder files and structure to mvc web server

Tags: browser, upload, directory

I need to be able to allow users to choose a folder on their computer and upload the whole contents to a web site.

It needs to be cross browser and platform compatible. HTML5 can be required.

I have read a lot about the limitations of the different browsers and that Chrome is the only one that really allows folder uploads.

I can place some requirements on the users, but not a lot.

I have also looked at JSZip and thought about zipping the client folder before uploading, but don't know how to get the selected folder from the user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Browser Folder Uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49655967/browser-folder-uploading)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I forgot that I had posted this question and asked it differently recently. There was an answer posted. Here is that thread:

[Browser Folder Uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49655967/browser-folder-uploading)