# Browser Folder Uploading

Tags: html, browser, upload, directory

I would like to be able to have a user upload a folder with all the files and folders inside it and retain the hierarchy to my web app using just the browser.

I have searched and not found how to do this. Everyone says that it is a browser problem and I believe it because there is not browser standard for doing this.

I have found and played with many javascript implementations of uploading files. When I drag a folder onto them I can get the list of all the files, but the folders and hierarchy are all gone. If I use the ones that open a dialog to find a file none of them allow selecting a folder.

So how does Dropbox do it?

I can drag a whole folder onto either Chrome or Safari (on my mac) and both of them will upload the folders and files and retain the hierarchy in dropbox.

Doesn't anyone know how they do that so that I can do the same on my own web app that is browser based?

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46562869 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/8218074

Comment: Those look promising. I tried it in both Safari and Chrome and it did show the array with all the folder information. The question is actually uploading that to the server. I will have to play around with it. One of my challenges is that some of the folders have the same file name used inside, so I have to be able to attached the full path to the file stream that gets uploaded. At any rate, thank you. If it works I will let you know and you can turn this into an answer.

Comment: This is working great for me. Please convert your comment into an answer so I can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add some parameters to the input tag to support directory uploads: `webkitdirectory` for Webkit-based browsers (e.g., Chrome) and `mozdirectory` for Mozilla's browser (Firefox).

The HTML code could look like this:

```
<input type="file" webkitdirectory mozdirectory … />
```

You could have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46562869 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/8218074, which are answers to similar questions.

Comment: what about drag and drop into div - how does the webkitdirectory tag work there?

Comment: @richardwhitney you've probably already figured this out, but FYI: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/07/Drag-and-drop-a-folder-onto-Chrome-now-available (tldr; dragEvent.dataTransfer.items[n].webkitGetAsEntry() will get you a FileEntry or DirectoryEntry for each file system object drag-and-dropped onto your element).

Answer (score 1):

To upload folders from browser, you need to set a few attributes,

Chrome,firefox doesn't allow to select file/folder in the same go,
to do this you need set a few attributes.

1. `InputEl.setAttribute("directory",directory")`
2. `InputEl.setAttribute("webkitdirectory","webkitdirectory")`

To retain the folder structure.
You need to use `webkitrelativepath`

```html
 <input
      type="file"
      directory="directory"
      multiple
      webkitdirectory="webkitdirectory"
      id="files"
    />
```

```js
document.getElementById("files").addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  console.log(document.getElementById("files").files);//fileList
});
```

Convert fileList(readonly) to an Array and loop over them and store the
`webkitRelativePath`value and update them to your backend, that is a way to retain the dir structure have been uploaded.

***NOTE***: while uploading a file,`webkitRelativePath` will be `""` and for only when directory and webKitRelativePath attributes are present you are allowed to upload a folder and for these files only you will have `webkitRelativePath` with some value.

Comment: Thank you for this new information.